# Effective and polite way to end a phone conversation

Tags: politeness, phrase-request

What are some ways that I can let the other speaker know I want to finish a phone conversation and am going to hang up.

I frequently come across as too abrupt. Usually something along the lines of extended pause followed by goodbye.

Leaving the room you can say 我现在要走了，再见！ so there is some lead up to the goodbye. What are some good lead up sentences that I can use for ending a phone conversation?

Comment: 我现在要走了 => I now want to leave (is correct?)

Comment: @Xaade - 要 can also mean "going to" so here it means "I'm going to leave, see you later".

Comment: Rather than `我现在要走了，再见`, would `我走了，再见` suffice instead?

Comment: @cocowalla - The first one is more like "I'm leaving now", the second one is "I'm going". Both are fine.

Comment: There's also the (slightly odd looking) 我先走了, which I hear all the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When talking with friends I generally end with one of the following.

> 好，就这样吧 = That's it (kind of, hard to translate)
>
> 好，我走了啊 = I'm off now
>
> 好，下次再聊 = Talk again soon

Or of course, the very simple 好，拜拜！

Looking at that, I guess I like to say 好 a lot!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you are receiving the call, you could say

> 感谢你的来电 = Thanks for calling

If you are calling someone, you could say

> 感谢你的时间 = Thanks for your time

You could also say

> 我们再联系 = We will contact again

before saying goodbye and hangup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, these sound OK for formal conversation, but most of the time it is with friends. Can you provide some examples of how I can end a conversation with friends?

Comment: hmmm, do you really need to say something polite to end phone calls with friends? How would you end phone calls in a polite way in English?

Comment: I think he is saying that your answers are quite polite, and he is looking for something a little less formal. Although obviously the title asks for something polite...

Answer (score 4):

On the mainland, this is usually a somewhat drawn out process, usually ending with a sequence something along these lines:

｀好了...好了。。。那，就这样吧。。。挂了。。。啊｀

｀嗯，嗯，知道了。。。好了，好了， 好啊，。。。挂了｀

挂了 (I'm hanging up now!), sounds kind of abrupt and rude, but it's used all the time and it doesn't sound rude at all.  I'd would usually preface it with `那就这样｀ or the like.

Answer (score 4):

- if it's a close friend, then “那就先这样？改天我们再聊?" (how about we leave it off like this? we'll chat later?)
- if it's somebody you want to be polite/safe with, then "您看您还有什么事儿?" (is there anything more i can do/answer for you?)
- if it's a telemarketer and you are in a good mood, then "我现在没空.对不起挂了啊." (i'm busy sorry i have to hang up)
- if it's a telemarketer and you are in a bad mood, then "我没兴趣.别再骚扰我了!" (i'm not interested. leave me alone!/don't bother me again!)

@xiaohuozi, i'm assuming that you are a guy and i've tailored my answers to your gender group by recalling how my guy friends/relatives said in those occasions. Those answers can be tuned "softer" with more "啊" "哈" "了" "呢" if you were a woman.

Comment: Note that the 2nd one only implies your wish to hang up...it doesn't say 'goodbye' or 'hang up' explicitly...this usually is more polite in chinese culture.